# change page template based on querystring

Tags: kentico

I am using one page template which contains master page layout also. Now when i access the page having layout which is displaying in browser. Now i wanted here if i use querystring like below:

```html
http://localhost/Mywebsite/page?AppMode=true
```

then i wanted here to show only content of the page master layout should not be displayed with page content.

Currently i am using Kentico9.

Answer (score 1):

A page's template is not something you can do with a macro, however you can control a Page Placeholder webpart with a macro/querystring.

So in order to do what you want, this is what you'll need to do.

1. For the page's actual template, it will pretty much just be a 'blank' page template, with a Page Placeholder webpart in it.
2. For the page placeholder webpart, set the path to "." (so it shows this page), and the Page Template you can then set with a macro: `{% (Convert.ToBool(QueryString.AppMode, false) ? "NotAppModeTemplate" : "AppModeTemplate") %}`

Tell me if that does the trick for ya!  The only caviote is the only 'control' of the master template used is in the template settings, which can inherit the root or the nearest master template, so if you want one template to use 1 master page, and the other to use a different, you'll have to set the masterpages somewhere in their ancestry and then use the "Inherit from Level 0,1,2..." setting in the Page Template.

Comment: HI Trevaor, I used in master template conditional layout and that layout visible property i used macro querystring to make this visible on some condition except in content placeholder. and it is working as i expected. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this using Kentico's ASPX mode of development.  Do a simple check for the querystring and set the visibility of the placeholder in code behind.  If I were doing this in Portal mode, I'd do that with a macro on a webpart.

Comment: Hi Brenden, Thanks for reply. Currently i am using portal engine in kentico. for the same page how can i disable master layout based on the querystring? Could you please give me some brief idea?

Comment: Visibility property of each web part or zone allows macro. In your case this would be {?!AppMode?} or {?!AppMode|(default)false?}

Comment: Here my question is how would i disable only master layout and show only page content based on the querystring?

Comment: Make master page components (web parts/zones) invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I used in master page template conditional layout and that layout i used visible property with macro querystring with my condition except for my content place holder and it is working fine as i wanted.